# Have image inside multiple divs with css text and links on top. Don't know how to replicate the divs to put multiple on page with different css values

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to this stuff, so not sure if that topic heading makes any sense. Essentially my question / problem is this:

I have used this codepen as a base and tweaked the css / html to my requirements: http://codepen.io/Hornebom/pen/pgioy

Html I'm using is (had to take out links before it would let me post):

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="head">
    <span class="caption">
      <p><a href="#">Facecare</a>
      <a href="#">Body &amp; Massage Oils</a>
      <a href="#">Bath &amp; Shower</a>
      <a href="#">Soaps</a>
      <a href="#">Mosquito Repellent</a>
      <a href="#">Skin Healing Oil</a></p>
    </span>
  </div>
  <img src="#">
</div>
```

The css is:

```
.box, .box:before, .head, .caption  {display:block;}
.box:before, .head, .caption  {position:absolute;}
.box {
  position:relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:500px;
  height:255px;
  margin:5rem auto;
  padding-left:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s;
  transition: all 0.7s;
}
.box:before  {
  content:'Skincare'; text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; font-size: 40px!important; font-family: Vollkorn ; font-weight: 400 ; serif!important;  
  color:#fff ;
  top:13px;
  right:13px;
  padding:23px 17px;
  background: none;
  font-size:22px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition:     all 0.5s;
  -o-transition:      all 0.5s;
  transition:         all 0.5s;
}
.box:hover  {
  padding-left:0px;
}
.box:hover:before  {right:-300px;}
.head {
  height:100%;
  width:650px;
  top:0px;
  left:-250px;
  margin:0px;
  padding-left:20px;
  background:transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.45s;
  -ms-transition:     all 0.45s;
  -o-transition:      all 0.45s;
  transition:         all 0.45s;
}
.head:hover  {
  left:0px;
}
.caption {
  background: none;
  padding:10px
}

.caption a {
  margin-top:0px;
  color:#fff;
  font-size: 23px!important; 
  font-family: Vollkorn ; 
  font-weight: 400 ; serif!important; 
  line-height: 35px; 
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding-left:0px; 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition:     all 0.3s;
  -o-transition:      all 0.3s;
  transition:         all 0.3s;
}

.caption a:hover {padding-left:7px;}
```

I have lined 4 of these up on the page, I can't attach an image unfortunately as not enough reputation points, but if you want to see it in action: www.placemarkdigital.com/hali - password = passwordisnow

The links and background images I have been able to change in the html, but I'm stuck on how to go about changing the main box title in the upper right hand corner and the original position of the links before they slide in where some of the link text where it's longer is currently appearing before hover. I tried duplicating the css and changing the classes for the box, head and caption sections and then also changing in the html for each of the sections, but it's breaking the code.

Any ideas / suggestions would be awesome!

Thanks a lot in advance,
David

Comment: What exactly are the changes you are trying to make in terms of the links positions? Providing a codepen/jsfiddle of your working code (in addition or instead of the one you based it on) would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would advise against using CSS to input content wherever possible (e.g. using content:'Skincare';) .  It is very unlikely that search engine spiders will pick that up and, as they are the main headings of the various sections, you would not want that.

That said - that content:'Skincare' in the CSS is what is setting the title of skincare in your css line 176.  You would need a separate identifer for each .box.  You could add a distinct class to each one class=".box .boxtl",  class=".box .boxtr"  and then set the content specifically for each one.

```
.box.boxtl{content:'Title 1'; .... }
.box.boxtr{content:'Title 2'; .... }
```

..etc

I would rethink your approach to this if possible - you are changing the content with CSS and should really keep the content in your HTML and the design in your CSS.

You could produce a similar transition without all the ::before stuff.

CSS

```
.con{float: left; width: 1000px;}
.box,.caption{display: block; }
.box{
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid red;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

.boxone{
background: url(https://www.google.co.uk/logos/doodles/2015/81st-anniversary-of-the-loch-ness-monsters-most-famous-photograph-4847834381680640-hp.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;}
.boxtwo{background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nUQMxjCAhdPEJcpmEd9CwfO1q8NC0fkpR-HfKIB0RGKXOCwT9qd6w6LuhG5mOor8iXtSZ67xxMLplNwLl5EjeV3P1x8BfHW7ePdIfE0) 0 0 no-repeat;}

.box .info{
        float: left;
        width: 750px; margin-left: -250px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.7s; -moz-transition: all 0.7s; -ms-transition: all 0.7s; -o-transition: all 0.7s;
        transition: all 0.7s;
    }

    .box .info h2{float: right; width: 50%; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;}
    .box .info ul{float: left; width: 50%;}
    .box .info ul{list-style-type: none;}
    .box .info ul li{list-style-type: none;}

    .box:hover .info{margin-left: 0; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="con">

    <div class="box boxone">
        <div class="info">
            <h2><a href="#">Title One</a></h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Body &amp; Massage Oils</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bath &amp; Shower</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Soaps</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mosquito Repellent</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Skin Healing Oil</a></p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box boxtwo">
        <div class="info">
            <h2><a href="#">Another Title</a></h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Oranges</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pears</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kiwis</a></p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

`

Comment: Apologies if I have misunderstood the question.  As Tim Mclure says some more information would be useful.